# Is it permited to download javascript code to iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have an hybrid application, it's basically a website running from the application folder inside a UIWebview.

The problem is that I was planning to update my website by downloading the whole website from internet and then replacing the old website.

Today I found that Apple now provides the App Store Review Guidelines and among others there are the following rules:

> 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected
>
> 2.8 Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

Because my site has html, css and javascript, does that mean that my app will be rejected or is there any chance to be accepted?
What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: How did it go in the end? Did they accept the app, and did the app download JavaScript from your server?

Comment: Unfortunately, the project was cancelled. I can't guarantee that Apple approves it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the new text of of the application developer agreement, regarding downloading executable code:

> The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework.

This includes javascript and hybrid applications, so you should be fine.

Although, taking all of this into account, why didn't you just allow your app to take advantage of the iPhone webapp stuff? You still get an icon on the home screen, and get rid of the browser chrome without having to get Apple to approve your app.