# Load local website from the Documents folder in iPhone using phonegap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

We're making an app using phonegap to load it locally. Everything is
working fine, the problem is that our manager asked us to find a way
of update the whole site (if necesary) from internet and replace the
old one.
So far I created one method to do it when the website is copied to the
Documents folder but I found that the 'www' site folder is loaded from
the bundle of the application and in iPhone is not possible to modify
files inside the folder.

Some say it would not be permitted to do such a thing like changing substantial parts of the application this way...

Please, do you know any approach to solve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to copy files from the application bundle to the application's Documents directory? How to send an HTTP query? How to check if the "local website" is older than some other site somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: The main problem is that I will not be able to update this local website (found in the www folder) if it is inside the bundle (resources). Now, if I copy the website from the bundle to the Documents folder, though I can update files there, phonegap will always try to load the site from the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app will be rejected, if not right away, at a later date - you are changing the whole app after all. All app updates need to be reviewed by Apple.

Phonegap loads index.html in the www folder. All you need to do is change the appropriate location in the AppDelegate. You could always do ../../Documents/foo.html - try that out, or something similar..

Comment: Thanks Shazron!, Really sorry if I'm too reiterative but I just want to be sure, have you heard about something similar to update the entire app through internet before?, here's a question that I posted and though it was targeted to another issue, they didn't give this warning. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677632/is-it-permited-to-download-javascript-code-to-iphone