# Cordova: use html, javascript and css from another location

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to use `html`, `javascript` and `css` files from a location other than the application's `www` folder?

**Background**

When building a `Cordova/Phonegap` application there is a host application and the app code is packaged in a folder `www` inside the application directory structure (`.apk` for Android, `.ipa` for iOS and `.xap` for WP8).

There are implementations where it is possible to "replace" the contents of the `www` folder with other files or point to another location for your app code. `Intel XDK` has a [live update](http://developer.html5dev-software.intel.com/?q=node/136) feature, where you can select your application package in its app preview tool (a generic host application). `Phonegap` has a similar feature called [hydration](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/tools_hydration.md.html).

The `Cordova` host application has a kind of virtual file system pointing in the application package. For example in Android the `index.html` file in the `www` folder is addressed at `file:///android_asset/www/index.html`. These files can be addressed from the application, but NOT from externally started applications (they can't point to files located in the application package). Files should be copied to another location first. It is therefore not possible to really replace the files within the application package.

What I would like to do is have, for example a generic `index.html` page with the required Javascript, to load the files from another location. Initially on application startup the app code will be copied to this location, for updates the app can check for the availability of a new application package on the internet, download it and copy it to that location.

It would also provide a quick development cycle. For example for `Android` I can copy all files and folders of the `www` folder to the device with `adb push www /mnt/sdcard/myappwww`.

Is is permitted to replace the `html`, `javascript` and `css`? According to the answer on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677632/is-it-permited-to-download-javascript-code-to-iphone) it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

We solved it by building Cordova Bootstrapper (https://github.com/MacawNL/CordovaBootstrapper).
Cordova Bootstrapper allows you to provide a zip package with your app code. This package is extracted to a location on disk and the index.html file is executed. The code checks for a newer version of a package on the web, if available it downloads the new one and extracts it so you can update your app. Same functionality is available for content packages.

Answer (score 0):

> > It is therefor not possible to really replace the files within the application package

100% correct. once an app is packaged, its files are read only

> > What I would like to do is have for example a generic index.html page with the required Javascript to load the files from another location

I would recommend using a framework that supports templating, states and MVC.  These are based around the principal of 'single page' apps, and dynamically load in the necessary content for each view/state.  Some good examples of frameworks that I would recommend are AngularJS, Ionic Framework and EmberJS. Some good examples of libraries (not a complete app framework, but provides some of this type of functionality) are RequireJS (for dynamic loading of files) or BackBoneJS (useful for MVC and routing).

Comment: I'm using Typescript + Angular + Ionic in this case. But what could my initial index.html file look like to load all other information from a location outside the application package?

Comment: Just stumbled across a github repo at https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-standalone-hydration that could point me in the right direction...